# Error using embedded flow in Visualforce page - Flow not found

Tags: visualforce, visual-flows

I am getting an error *"Flow xxx is not found or doesn't have an active version. Please contact your administrator for more information"*.

Little background: There are two pages, Managed and Unmanaged. Managed page is part of a managed package and at runtime it dynamically includes the Unmanaged page using apex:include pageName="{!dynamicPage}. The idea is to run different flows based on some data.

Unmanaged page is local to the org where the managed package is installed. Unmanaged page embeds a flow that is also unmanaged and created locally in the org where the managed package is installed.

When I run the Unmanaged page, it shows the flow and performs as expected. But when I invoke the Managed page, I get the error mentioned above.

Am I missing something? Does anyone faced similar issue?

Thanks!